# Access VueRouter outside Vue components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to access the VueRouter outside of Vue components.

I've tried importing Vue in a JavaScript file. In this file I can access `Vue.http` but not `Vue.router` or `Vue.$router`. The last 2 return undefined.

#### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import routes from './config/routes'
import store from './store'
import * as rootUrl from './config/rootUrl'



//Routing support
Vue.use(VueRouter);
//Backend support
Vue.use(VueResource);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})

new Vue({
    store,
    router,
}).$mount('#app')

Vue.http.get(rootUrl.url, {Accept: "application/json"}).then(response => {
    let data = response.body
    store.commit('SET_APP_DATA', { data: {
        'title': data.title,
        'peopleUrl': data.people,
        'eventsUrl':  data.events
    }})
    store.commit('SET_READY')
})
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your router?

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've used it only from components but you could try following in case you're using common boilerplate where routes are defined under router/index.js then you just import it like:

```
import Router from '../router';
```

After it is possible to use it in code e.g.

```
Router.push('/mypage')
```

Not sure if it works but give it a try.

Comment: I'm just starting with Vue myself and this was one of the first issues that occured to me. Hope you find solution.

Comment: This answer is correct, GroovyP just had router incorrectly set up

Comment: The trick here is to get the router instance directly, not via `useRouter`.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by exporting my router instead of my routes in routes.js (now router.js)

```
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})
```

Any file can then access the router with

```
import router from 'config/router'
```

Answer (score 3):

You've defined your router with this statement

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})
```

So all you need to do to access it outside Vue is use

```
router.push(...)
```

Or whatever else you want to do.

If you want to use it in some other file, you may need to expose it on the `window`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the router to your `Vue` constructor in the same file that you create and initialize your `vue` instance.

```
Vue.$router = router
```

Then use it as you first tried.

```js
Vue.$router.push(...)
```

If using `Typescript`, you can augment the `VueContructor` to enable type checking and autocompletion.

*mytypes.d.ts*

```
import {VueRouter} from "vue-router/types/router";
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface VueConstructor {
    $router: VueRouter
  }
}
```